# How to get one string from an array in a Cloud Firestore?

Tags: android, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array in Cloud Firestore:

[image]

How do I get one String from an array in Android Studio so that when I click a button in a TextView application, this value is assigned?

my current (not working) code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button mButtonGive;
TextView mTextPromo;

FirebaseFirestore mRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference mDelRef = mRef.collection("Promocode").document("Delivery").collection("Promocode");
CollectionReference mIviRef = mRef.collection("Promocode").document("Ivi").collection("Promocode");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mButtonGive = findViewById(R.id.mButtonGive);
    mTextPromo = findViewById(R.id.mTextPromo);

    mButtonGive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDelRef.get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();

                            String text = list.toString();
                            mTextPromo.setText(text);
                        }
                    });

        }
    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see in the screenshot your `Delivery` is a document, in which you have `Promocode` array field. In that case your reference to the document is:

```
DocumentReference mDelRef = mRef.collection("Promocode").document("Delivery");
```

And you then get the promocodes with:

```
delRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                List<String> promocodes = (List<String) document.get("Promocode");
                Log.d(TAG, "Promocodes: " + promocodes);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, I saw something similar in the Firestore documentation, but how do I get this data in a TextView?

Comment: You do that by calling `setText` on the relevant view. But on Stack Overflow it's always best to isolate the problem. My answer focuses purely on Firestore, since that seemed to be the cause of the problem. If the `Log` statements show the correct field, that problem is solved. If you're having trouble setting the correct value to a text field, that problem should also be reproducible without Firestore. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more on how and why to isolate problems.

Comment: It works, but I wrote that I need to get only one value from the array, that is, only "del1", but the code you wrote gives the entire array D/MainActivity: DocumentSnapshot data: {Promocode=[del1, del2, del3, del4, del5]} and D/MainActivity: Promocodes: [del1, del2, del3, del4, del5]

Comment: Since I can't know what value you want, I showed you how to loop over the values so that you can pick the value that you're looking for. Since the values are in a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), you can just call `promocodes.get(0)` for example to get the first code. I highly recommend doing some self-studying and showing what you tried based on my answer if you're having a hard time adapting it to your needs.